# C - strcmp() two strings from arrays

Tags: c, arrays, string, strcmp

I am comparing two strings each coming from arrays.

```
while(countX<10){
    if(strcmp(scanWord[countX], currentWord[countX]) == 0)
        {scoreCurrent++;scoreCurrent++;}
    countX++;
}
```

"scanWord[countX]" and "currentWord[countX]" don't compare; each time coming up that they aren't the same even if they are. It works if I compare things that aren't those and I have printed them to screen to check too. They just don't seem to play well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not enough information I'm afraid. The way you describe it and seeing your code, it should work. Since it does not work you might want to show how these words end up in the arrays. Minor quibble: why twice `scoreCurrent`?

Comment: @Jongware

fgets(currentWord[countX], 20, stdin);

fscanf(dataMarking, "%[^:]:%[^\n]%*c", scanWord[countX], scanDescription[countX])

Does this help? And the two scoreCurrents is from laziness.

Comment: How do you declare `scanWord` and `currentWord`?

Comment: Yippie. Another occasion of "you forgot to remove the trailing hard return."

Comment: `fgets()` leaves the newline in the string. Are you sure both strings have newlines?

Comment: I think you nailed it @Barmar :)

Comment: @Barmar Ah, that might just be it. How in this case would one add or remove a newline to make it work?

Comment: @Jongware Then how does one do this in this situation?

Comment: One searches SO to find this *exact* "problem" (quotes because [it is mentioned in the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgets)) dozens of times. F.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input

Comment: @Jongware Thank you, sorry for being so ignorant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're reading the line, remove the newline:

```
char *line = fgets(currentWord[countX], 20, stdin);
if (line) {
    int len = strlen(line);
    if (line[len-1] == '\n') {
        line[len-1] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: `n` is always going to be >0, unless an error occured, but it is not a number. fgets returns "`str` on success, NULL on failure" -- where `str` is a pointer to the start of the buffer.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it to use `strlen` to find the last character.

Comment: That's okay, but (sorry to keep on nagging) there is no particular need to create a new `char *`. You can use `strlen(currentWord[countX])` immediately.

Comment: I know. But since I want to check for success, I figured I would create a short variable name instead of indexing.

Comment: Ah -- I see. I'd typically use `if (!fgets(..)) { ..error.. }`. I guess we can leave this as a matter of "personal style" then.

Answer (score 0):

The question as I see it:

> "scanWord[countX]" and "currentWord[countX]" don't compare; each time coming up that they aren't the same even if they are.

How do you KNOW the two values are the same? Print them out. Print out the length too. If dealing with Unicode of any sort, print out the individual bytes in hexadecimal, because two Unicode characters that look identical may actually be different.

Because the computer will never say the strings are different if they are really the same. The answer to the question as I read it is that the strings actually are different.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Zack: The "accepted answer" doesn't answer the question either. He took a guess and got lucky.